# implicit return with variable assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

according to the most popular style guides:

```
# this a bad
def some_function
  return "some value"
end

# this is good
def some_function
  "some value"
end
```

I'm working with Ruby on Rails and I often see code like this, which those style guides don't mention:

```
def some_function(x)
  result = some_calculations(x)
  result
end
```

I've tried this and it works, so I don't understand the rationale of explicitly returning the variable after the assignment in the next line:

```
# this works as well
def some_function(x)
  result = some_calculations(x)
end
```

Comment: Why we need to assign to a variable when we can just directly return the statement.
When there is the statement at the last line of the method and the result of that statement should be return we don't need to store that in a variable unless it's a instance variable and being used in other method.

In your example you need to assign that to a variable at all.

You might need a variable in case where you have other instruction running after assigning the value to variable and return that variable after performing other operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! By doing other operations you mean changing the value of the variable without re-assigning it? @HirenBhalani

Comment: Yes, and probably figure out other thing based on that variable without changing it, but return that variable.

Comment: @sava128 : Depending on your warning level, your last solution would warn you that `result` is assigned, but not used. I don't see any purpose in assigning to a local variable, if it is the last statement in a block or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no rationale in assigning the local variable at all since it goes out of scope immediately. So the "correct way" to write the method is actually:

```
def some_function(x)
  some_calculations(x)
end
```

Even if you do what to do some operations with the result you can use `then` and `tap` instead of assigning a local variable:

```
def some_function(x)
  some_calculations(x).then do |value|
    value ** 2
  end
end
```

Comment: or `alias_method :some_function, :some_calculations`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What you said makes total sense.